# jQuery :contains as a selector

Tags: jquery

I am trying to use :contains as a selector:

```
    var test = jQuery(":contains('"+content_uq_name+"')").css();
    console.log(test);
```

I am getting a jQuery error:

```
TypeError: a is undefined


...eChild(b)):c(a))},camelCase:function(a){return a.replace(p,"ms-").replace(q,r)},...
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: `.css()` need an argument...

Comment: I think the problem is `.css()` - it needs at least 1 argument

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon maybe I am understanding it wrong. I need to find the element that contains the given text and replace the given text with something else. Is this possible?

Comment: then why you use `.css`?

Comment: in your browser console check what does `jQuery(":contains('"+content_uq_name+"')")` returns. you can use [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) to replace the content

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon it was just a test.

Comment: @Anonymous your question is *"I am getting a jQuery error, What am I doing wrong?"* and your answer is: `.css()` need an argument to work, it has nothing to do with `:contains`. If you want to do something and it doesn't work, post the relevant code, not your.... test.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon Wou! relax! I just made the question in the wrong way ;) No problem if you don't know the answer. Thanks anyway.

Comment: *"Relax"*? I do not have any anger in me? How could you detect an emotion in a comment that try to tell you how SO work? Maybe it is because the the lack of emoticon! ;) As for your answer, I know how, but a SO policy is to [show us what you've tried.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) We're an help center, not a free programming team. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After your comment i suggest one solution using [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)

```js
$("div:contains('test')").each(function() {
  $(this).text("test1");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>test</div>
<div>car</div>
<div>test</div>
<div>test</div>
<div>test</div>
<div>test</div>
```

You have to specify the elements you want to replace text.

Comment: Ok the problem is that it should get all the items that contains that string, not only the divs. For example I have that string in the src attribute of an image. That is not a DIV but I need to select that anyway. How can I achieve this?

Comment: @Anonymous: you should ask another question for that

Answer (score 0):

`.css()` needs an argument. From the [api documentation](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

[image: console output]